# How to expand images without moving surrounding elements in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my html code, I have a table (3 by 3), and each cell has an image. I want it so that when you hover your mouse over any of the images, it animates and becomes bigger, and when you move your mouse away from it, then it animates back to its original size.

The main issue is that it can't affect the x,y coordinate of the other elements. Like when I attempt to increase its size, the table cell gets expanded too and moves the other images.

I want it so that everything else stays exactly where it was, the image expanding just goes on top of them.

Does anyone know how to do this in, css3, jquery, javascript?

**Note: The image should expand from all sides evenly.**

Thanks

Comment: Can you create fiddle what you are trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give position to absolute and z-index to some +ve value.. something like below.. 
your fiddle.. [http://jsfiddle.net/QMtB3/3](http://jsfiddle.net/QMtB3/3/)/

```
.alignright table tr td img
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
.alignright table tr td img:hover
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:-75px;
    margin-top:-75px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: this is making the image expand from the bottom right, it should be expanding from all sides evenly. In other words the xy coordinate of the center of the enlarged image should be the same as the xy coordinate of the center of the original image.

Comment: In your Question (The main issue is that it can't affect the x,y coordinate of the other elements. ).. Answer is suggested for that one only..

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with CSS using `transform: scale(2);`.

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<img src="example.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
img{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
}
img:hover{
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
}
```

I think that works fine with your table.

Comment: Read his requirement. He wants to make the resized image appear over other images.